# Check network on app launch - cordova 5.1.1

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to detect network on app launch, if device is not connected to internet then display alert message and let user close the app.

In my config I have `<content src="redirect-to-external-url" />`

What I want to achieve:

1. On app launch display splashscreen
2. Detect network, if no internet detected then display message else redirect to url

Is it possible to do, if not what are alternate ways?

Many Thanks,
Nishikant

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple plugin that enable you to check on WIFI connectivity ,Bluetooth , Location and many other details you want to check on the device

Check it Here [Cordova Diagnostic Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic)

EDIT : if wifi information not satisfying so you need something like [connection plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova/connection/connection.html)

it check all types of internet connection :

- Connection.UNKNOWN
- Connection.ETHERNET
- Connection.WIFI
- Connection.CELL_2G
- Connection.CELL_3G
- Connection.CELL_4G
- Connection.NONE

Comment: You want to check the internet connectivity am I right ? if I was right so please read the edited part in my answer

Comment: The connection plugin is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

We currently use the 'easy way' using an AJAX call. In the success callback you  can call your redirect code and in the error callback you can display the error message.

Comment: I am not looking for AJAX,  but out of curiosity how do you redirect after that?

Comment: You might not need the actual result, but it's an easy way to check if the network is working properly.

In javascript you can redirect using `location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com"`

In our case, we call an endpoint that returns the needed HTML directly and we then just replace the body with the new markup (using `$("#container").html(ajaxResult)` - This is also the reason we went with an AJAX call to check network connectivity, we needed it anyway and just handled failure "gracefully enough".

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved it is:

In config: `<content src="index.html" />`

Below is JS.

```
var conType = navigator.connection.type;
if(conType == 'none' || conType == Connection.NONE || conType == Connection.none)
{
    window.location = "redirect-url"; 
    }
else{
        //Display network error
    }
```